# MachinePrecision versus $MachinePrecision in NDSolve

Tags: numerics, machine-precision, arbitrary-precision

I'd like to understand why one of these inputs gives me an error and the other doesn't:

```
s1 = 
 NDSolve[
   {x'[t] == x[t], x[0] == SetPrecision[1., 10]}, 
   {x}, {t, 0, 1}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision
 ][[1]]
```

> NDSolve::precw: The precision of the differential equation ({{(x^[Prime])[t]==x[t],x[0]==1.000000000},{},{},{},{}}) is less than WorkingPrecision (15.954589770191003`). >>

```
(* Out: {x -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0, 1.000000000000000}}, <>]} *)
```

versus

```
s2 = 
 NDSolve[
   {x'[t] == x[t], x[0] == SetPrecision[1., 10]}, 
   {x}, {t, 0, 1}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision
 ][[1]]

(* Out: {x -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 1.}}, <>]} *)
```

Notice that the only difference is the fact that `$MachinePrecision` got changed to `MachinePrecision`. Also, oddly enough, the resulting answers are not identical:

```
x1[t_] = Evaluate[x[t] /. s1];
x2[t_] = Evaluate[x[t] /. s2];

Plot[x1[t] - x2[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Using `$MachinePrecision` in the current version of *Mathematica* forces the (admittedly counterintuitive in this case) use of the *arbitrary-precision* numerics. `MachinePrecision` is the right setting to use if you want to stay within machine precision computations, but you do run the risk of hitting instabilities if you are the unlucky sort.

Comment: If that's the case, why does changing the precision to 20 eliminate the error? Do you mean to switch those two statements?

Comment: Again: the symbol with the dollar sign uses *arbitrary precision*, while the other one is the switch to use machine precision. Mull on this for a bit. Your use of `SetPrecision[1., 10]` is unfortunate in the former case, since `10 < $MachinePrecision`, which is why you get the error observed.

Comment: This confused me for a bit as well. Here is how I understand it now; perhaps it will help you too. `$MachinePrecision` is the number of digits of precision that is roughly equivalent to running a native machine-precision calculation on your system. You can evaluate it, and it will return a real number, on my system for instance ca. 15.9. Now think of it this way: `WorkingPrecision -> someNumber` forces the use of the arbitrary precision engine, with `someNumber` digits of precision. ...

Comment: ... Similarly `WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision` triggers the use of the arbitrary precision system, with a number of digits of precision that mimics the native machine's precision, *but now with error tracking* thanks to the arbitrary precision engine. A comparative example can be found in the "Possible Issues" section of the docs on [`$MachinePrecision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$MachinePrecision.html).

Comment: Additionally arb.-prec. numbers use extra guard bits, so that rounding error is different with MachinePrecision & $MachinePrecision.

Comment: I think I've stepped out of my depth here haha. @MarcoB's reference to the Possible Issues section of \$MachinePrecision helped me formulate what it is I'm confused about: what's the difference between "machine number computations" and "machine number resolution"? Also, if I were to simply use WorkingPrecision -> 15.9546 (which =\$MachinePrecision on my computer), would the internal behavior be the same as using \$MachinePrecision, MachinePrecision, or neither?

Comment: @Max I think there is no difference between the two, at least in the way I would use them. They both refer to fast, machine-precision calculations. Since `$MachinePrecision` evaluates to that number (15.9..), I fully expect that `WorkingPrecision -> 15.9546` and `WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision` will lead to the same results on your machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was looking for a previous question of which this might be a duplicate; although many previous discussions hinge on precision issues, and the difference has been mentioned in comments, I could not dredge up an explicit discussion of `$MachinePrecision` vs `MachinePrecision` through the SE search engine, so I thought I might sum up the discussion in comments, in hopes that it may be useful as an easier-to-find future reference.

---

The difference between `MachinePrecision` and `$MachinePrecision` took me some time to grasp at first. I also find that the documentation does a poor job of explaining the difference between the two. Here is how I understand it now; perhaps it will help others too.

`$MachinePrecision` is the number of digits of precision that is equivalent to running a native machine-precision calculation on your system (i.e. using machine numbers). You can evaluate it, and it will return a machine-precision real number:

```
$MachinePrecision
(* Out: 15.9546 *)
```

On the one hand, `MachinePrecision` is a switch to indicate that numerical functions should use machine numbers as implemented in the hardware of your particular computer, and no precision tracking. This is by far the fastest option, and it is chosen by default.

Now consider that setting `WorkingPrecision -> someNumber` forces the use of the arbitrary precision engine, with `someNumber` digits of precision and error tracking.

Similarly, then, `WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision` triggers the use of the arbitrary precision system, with a number of digits of precision that mimics the native machine's precision, but *now with error tracking* thanks to the arbitrary precision engine.

A comparative example can be found in the "Possible Issues" section of the [docs on $MachinePrecision](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/%24MachinePrecision.html).

[Michael](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) also [mentioned](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/117876/machineprecision-versus-machineprecision-in-ndsolve#comment318474_117876) in his comment that arbitrary-precision numbers use extra guard bits, so that rounding error is different between `MachinePrecision` and `$MachinePrecision`.

---

Here are a few relevant previous discussions from this site:

- [A problem about function N](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55292/27951)
- [ReplaceAll and Limit don't give correct results for this expression under extreme variables](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10820/27951)
- [How can I increase the precision of my computation?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/103714/27951)

Comment: A historical note: in versions before 5, `N[x, $MachinePrecision]` was the way to produce a machine precision evaluation of a number. For some reason, version 5 introduced `MachinePrecision` as a separate entity which effectively did what `$MachinePrecision` used to do, and now `$MachinePrecision` is then left to produce arbitrary-precision results.

Comment: @J.M. As though the situation was not complicated enough already :-) More seriously, if you (or anybody) have any corrections / additions to what I wrote above, please feel free to edit away! I was surprised not to find an authoritative answer on this subject already, so I wonder if I might have simply missed it in my search.